# Put Picker at the bottom of tableview

Tags: iphone

I want to put Picker at th bottom of table view.
Can you teach me how to do this?

I want to build Table view with Picker like a native iPhone Clock app.

```
//picker
 UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:<#(CGRect)frame#>];
```

Answer (score 1):

two ways

1.in view add table and then picker

2.in view add table and add picker in tableviewfooter

what u need

Comment: Thank you! 

I need your 2. I want to build Table view with Picker like a native iPhone Clock app.

best,

Comment: do u want statically or after selecting the cell